# How to return multiple parse failures within Parsec's monadic context?

Tags: parsing, haskell, error-handling, parsec, parse-error

I have a grammar I am parsing which consists of *exactly two* required and unique logical parts, `Alpha` and `Beta`. These parts can be defined in any order, `Alpha` before `Beta` or visa-vera. I would like to provide robust error messages for the less tech-savvy users.

In the example below there are cases where multiple parse failures exist. I concatenate the failure message `String`s with the [**`unlines`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unlines) function and pass the resulting concatenation into the [**`fail`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:fail) combinator. This creates a  [**`ParseError`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Error.html#t:ParseError) value with a *single* [**`Message`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Error.html#t:Message) value when [**`parse`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.7/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:parse) is called on `grammarDefinition`.

**Example Scenario:**

```
import Data.Either                   (partitionEithers)
import Data.Set                      (Set)
import Text.Parsec                   (Parsec)
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

data Result = Result Alpha Beta
type Alpha  = Set (Int,Float)
type Beta   = Set String

grammarDefinition :: Parsec String u Result
grammarDefinition = do
    segments <- partitionEithers <$> many segment
    _        <- eof
    case segments of
      (     [],      []) -> fail $ unlines [missingAlpha, missingBeta]
      (      _,      []) -> fail $ missingBeta
      (     [],       _) -> fail $ missingAlpha
      ((_:_:_), (_:_:_)) -> fail $ unlines [multipleAlpha, multipleBeta]
      (      _, (_:_:_)) -> fail $ multipleBeta
      ((_:_:_),       _) -> fail $ multipleAlpha
      (    [x],     [y]) -> pure $ Result x y
    where
      missingAlpha     = message "No" "alpha"
      missingBeta      = message "No" "beta"
      multipleAlpha    = message "Multiple" "alpha"
      multipleBeta     = message "Multiple" "beta"
      message x y      = concat [x," ",y," defined in input, ","exactly one ",y," definition required"]

-- Type signature is important!
segment :: Parsec String u (Either Alpha Beta)
segment = undefined -- implementation irrelevant
```

I would like the [**`ParseError`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Error.html#t:ParseError) to contain *multiple* [**`Message`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Error.html#t:Message) values in the case of multiple failures. This should be possible due to the existence of the [**`addErrorMessage`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Error.html#t:addErrorMessage) function. I am not sure hw to supply multiple failure within the Parsec monadic context, before the result is materialized by calling [**`parse`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.7/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:parse).

**Example Function:**

```
fails :: [String] -> ParsecT s u m a
fails = undefined -- Not sure how to define this!
```

**How do I supply *multiple*** `Message` **values to the** `ParseError` **result *within* Parsec's monadic context?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend transitioning from [**`Parsec`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) to newer and more extensible [**`Megaparsec`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) library.

[This exact issue](https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec/issues/43) has been resolved since version `4.2.0.0`.

Multiple parse error [**`Message`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-4.2.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Error.html#v:Message)s can easily be created with the following function:

```
fails :: MonadParsec m => [String] -> m a
fails = failure . fmap Message
```

Answer (score 2):

`fail` in this case is equivalent to [`parserFail`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v:parserFail) defined in `Text.Parsec.Prim`:

```
parserFail :: String -> ParsecT s u m a
parserFail msg
    = ParsecT $ \s _ _ _ eerr ->
      eerr $ newErrorMessage (Message msg) (statePos s)
```

Since `newErrorMessage` and `addErrorMessage` both create a `ParseError`,
this variation of `parserFail` should also work:

```
parserFail' :: String -> ParsecT s u m a
parserFail' msg
    = ParsecT $ \s _ _ _ eerr ->
      eerr $ theMessages s
where
  theMessages s =
    addErrorMessage (Message "blah") $
      addErrorMessage (Expect "expected this") $
        newErrorMessage (Message msg) (statePos s)
```

which should push 3 messages onto the error message list.

Also in that module, have a look at `label` and `labels` which is
the only place where `addErrorMessage` is used. `labels` is just a multi-message
version of the `<?>` operator. Note how it uses `foldr` to build up a compound
error message:

```
labels :: ParsecT s u m a -> [String] -> ParsecT s u m a
labels p msgs =
    ParsecT $ \s cok cerr eok eerr ->
    let eok' x s' error = eok x s' $ if errorIsUnknown error
                  then error
                  else setExpectErrors error msgs
        eerr' err = eerr $ setExpectErrors err msgs

    in unParser p s cok cerr eok' eerr'

 where
   setExpectErrors err []         = setErrorMessage (Expect "") err
   setExpectErrors err [msg]      = setErrorMessage (Expect msg) err
   setExpectErrors err (msg:msgs)
       = foldr (\msg' err' -> addErrorMessage (Expect msg') err')
         (setErrorMessage (Expect msg) err) msgs
```

The only gatcha is that you need access to the `ParsecT` constructor which
is not exported by `Text.Parsec.Prim`. Maybe you can find a way to use `labels`
or another way around that problem. Otherwise you could always include your
own hacked version of `parsec` with your code.

Comment: Your answer was very informative, however [**`Data.Parsec.Prim`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.8/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html) does not export the `ParsecT` constructor. This makes most of the solutions you presented form the module's source unusable outside the library's exposed interface.

Comment: Glad to know that using `labels` worked out for you.

Comment: It's not perfect because I would prefer `Message` instead of `Expect` values, but is is probably as close as I will get. Plus the `fails` definition is short and sweet ;)

Answer (score 0):

We can leverage the fact that [**`ParsecT`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.8/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#t:ParsecT) is an instance of [**`MonadPlus`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus) to combine the definition of [**`mzero`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mzero) with the function [**`labels`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.8/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v:labels) to derive the desired result:

```
fails :: [String] -> ParsecT s u m a
fails = labels mzero
```

***Note:*** The [**`ParseError`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.8/docs/Text-Parsec-Error.html#t:ParseError) has many [**`Expect`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.8/docs/Text-Parsec-Error.html#t:Message) values, not many [**`Message`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.8/docs/Text-Parsec-Error.html#t:Message) values...